# How to accomplish this with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know how will you do something like the following:

When you click "list 2" the "text 2" appears in the paragraph with a class of message. And when click "text 3", the "text 3" appears instead and so on.

Its challenging because you don't show the actual list text but another text from other place! Any thoughts on this? Thank you so much for helping me : )

```
<p class="message"></p>

<ul>
<li>list 1</li>
<li>list 2</li>
<li>list 3</li>
</ul>

<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 3</p>
```

Comment: good use of class attribute will help this conundrum

Comment: Thanks, I think so too, but I'm going to add more content to the list, about 1000's record, so targeting content with different class will result in a long js code!

Comment: not with GOOD use of classes - without classes the js code will be even longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this ?

```js
var paragraphs = $('p').not('.message');

$('li').on('click', function(e) {
  var i = $(e.target).index();
  $('.message').html($(paragraphs[i]).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="message"></p>

<ul>
<li>list 1</li>
<li>list 2</li>
<li>list 3</li>
</ul>

<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 3</p>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I'm after, thank you so much I will study the code. Thank you again!!